# Spinner onItemChange by Spinner value selection on Android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have two spinners. I am receiving information from server and displaying it in the first spinner. My doubt is that "Second spinner should change automatically depending on the selection of the first spinner values".
How can i achieve this? I have wasted 2 days for that .Please help.

Comment: is second spinner value also come from server?

Comment: provide some code of your spinner section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't exactly been generous in your explanation of your issue. The following should help you get on your feet with what issue that you may be having.

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            spinner2.setSelection(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
  }
```